# this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++, dll, export

I have a **this declaration has no storage class or type specifier** problem when implementing a C++ dll. Here is the code

CarPool.h code:

```
#pragma once
#define DllExport _extern "C" long __declspec(dllexport)

DllExport CartToPol(char* fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel);
DllExport PolToCart(char* fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel);
```

CarPool.cpp code

```
    // CarPool.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "CarPool.h"

    DllExport CartToPol(char* fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

DllExport PolToCart(char* fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel)
{
    return TRUE;

}
```

Anyone has any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it was the underscore on extern.

It should be

```
#define DllExport extern "C" long __declspec(dllexport)
```

instead of

```
#define DllExport _extern "C" long __declspec(dllexport)
```

Thanks.